# How to apply a function to a range of columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply a function to the values in a range of columns in my dataframe, but it shows an error:

This is my dataframe

[image]

```
#define a function to change missing values to NaN
def change_missing(num):
    if (num != None) & (type(num) != int) & (type(num) != float):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return num

Energy.iloc[:,1:4].apply(change_missing)
```

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Energy Supply')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), which calls the specified function *for each cell of each column*, instead of [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), which calls the specified function *for each column only*:

```
Energy.iloc[:,1:4].applymap(change_missing)
```

Comment: But why? What about the usage of `&`? and usage of `type` to check instanceship? and a better pandas way to rewrite all if at all? you made it work allright, but not a qualified answer this is, let me say. But if you need reputation, let me upvote you

Comment: lol, thank you @Neither! Yeah, the code could actually be rewritten better, but why bother? This question doesn't show enough research to make me want to work hard... :)